# Не совпадает размер файла на разных ftp

Tags: ftp

Кладу один и тот же файл на разные фтп. Но размер не совпадает. Причем пробовал заливать хоть в ASCII режиме, хоть бинарном. Соответственно вопрос - как можно узнать реальный размер файла по ftp-протоколу?

Comment: есть много вариантов. От просто банально режим не удалось выставить и файл не  был закачан до конца до хитрых настроек фтп и шальных фаерволов/антивирусов.

Хотя бы размеры файлов привели. Пробовали ли назад файл скачать и сравнить?

Comment: А как эти размеры соотносятся с реальностью?

Comment: Файл целый и работает. С ним проблем нет. Я его закачиваю на многие сервера. И почти всегда он весит 13179 байт. А вот попался один сервер на котором файл весит 13477 байт. Пробовал менять режими передачи - все одно. Причем если закачать файл через менеджер файлов на этот хост то размер как надо 13179. А именно если по ftp-протоколу то 13477.

Answer (score 1):

Размер файла должен быть везде одинаков, так как он зависит от содержимого. Есть размер содержимого файла в байтах, а есть размер, который файл занимает на диске. Второй размер зависит от того сколько кластеров на диске он занимает. Потому что если размер файла 524 байта, то на диске он занимает 1024 байта, если размер кластера 512 и 2048 байт, если 2048. Этот размер может меняться, первый нет.
Байты одни и те же должны везде быть и контрольная сумма совпадать.

Попробуйте установить себе на компьютер какой-нибудь бесплатный FTP-сервер или demo c ограничением по времени. Можно пару-тройку. FTP-сервер берет файлы, которые лежат на диске, в какой-то локальной папке, поэтому можно её расшарить в настройках и положить туда файл. Скачать его, затем сравнить размер и контрольную сумму. Закачать этот файл обратно на свой FTP-сервер в другую папку. Сравнить два локальных файла.

Также для просмотра содержимого FTP можно воспользоваться файловыми менеджерами, например, FAR. Там есть плагин (даже по-моему в стандартную инсталляцию он входит) по Alt + F1 (F2) вызывается.
То есть смысл в том, что FTP-сервер размещает и отдает реальные файлы с локального для себя диска и их размеры должны совпадать c точностью до байта.

Если же размеры файлов не совпадают, то не совпадают и файлы. Значит файл неправильно закачан. Либо нужно обновить папку, чтобы перечитался новый размер файла.

Comment: Для анализа размера файла я беру тот размер который отдает ОС. Мерять каждый файл в байтах очень накладно. С кластерами я понимаю. Может быть есть метод узнать реальный размер средствами ОС? Сейчас я использую ls -la.

Comment: Провожу эксперименты и выяснил, что в этом "особенном" сервере просто сохраняется \n\r. 5 строк - файл больше на 5 байт. Вот только зачем он это делает? Пробовал менять режими подключения - все равно.

Comment: Файловые менеджеры с размерами файлов помогают, например mc commander. Думаю, надо гуглить именно под этот сервер проблему, скорее дело в его настройках каких-то (конфиг или возможно баг в версии). Чудес на свете не бывает. Содержимое при передаче не должно изменятся, значит ошибка в сервере FTP. Вариант, что файл не докачан, насколько я понял полностью отброшен. Если в этот конкретно файл добавляет, надо другие еще файлы попробовать: просто текст, нулевого размера, другой бинарник. Тогда проблему можно четче очертить и закономерность выяснится.